# Compare number from a txt file with an number in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to read text file which contain numbers line by line in

> test.txt

```
10.5
0.52
78.5
29.8
45
13
21.45
0.02
0.99
1.00
```

I want to read the number one by one and compare it with 30. I am not getting how can I do it.

I tried this but its not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=~/test.txt

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line
        if [[ "$line > 30" | bc) -eq "1" ]]; then
            echo Greater
        else
            echo Smaller
        fi
done < $file
```

Please note: I am new to programing

Comment: Start with https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output

Comment: You should have gotten an error message from your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
        if [[ "$line > 30" | bc) -eq "1" ]]; then
```

should be:

```
        if [[ $(echo "$line > 30" | bc) -eq "1" ]]; then
```

Comment: Hello Barmar, I tried but I am getting error as `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M`

Comment: Use `dos2unix test.txt` to remove the carriage returns from the file.

Comment: Although this works, it is better to do the test without resorting to `bc`: `if [[ line -gt 30 ]]` or `if [ "$line" -gt 30 ]` (IMO, the latter is better, since you get an error message when $line is not an integer, but there are arguments in favor of `[[`)

Comment: Consider using the clearer `(( x == y ))` instead of `[[ x -eq y ]]` or `[ x -eq y ]` for math operations.

Answer (score 1):

A shell is a tool to create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to other tools. The mandatory POSIX tool that shell has available to manipulate text (as you're trying to do) is awk. So the right way to do what you're trying to do in a shell is to just call awk and let awk do the rest:

```
$ awk '{print $1, ($1 > 30 ? "Greater" : "Smaller")}' test.txt
10.5 Smaller
0.52 Smaller
78.5 Greater
29.8 Smaller
45 Greater
13 Smaller
21.45 Smaller
0.02 Smaller
0.99 Smaller
1.00 Smaller
```

I just copied the logic from your code but of course "Smaller" should really be "Smaller or equal to".

Read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to learn the very important lesson of why not to write shell loops to manipulate text.

Comment: D'oh! I was so focused on the bc part ...

Comment: @glennjackman [That's just what they'll be expecting us to do](https://c.tenor.com/p1cde0wHiYUAAAAd/airplane-thats-what-they-expect.gif).

Answer (score 0):

Using a pipeline of unix tools will probably be a lot faster (particularly as this only calls `bc` once)

```bash
cmp=30

paste test.txt <(sed "s/\$/ > $cmp/" test.txt | bc) \
| awk '{$2 = ($2 == 0) ? "Smaller" : "Greater"; print}' \
| column -t
```

```
10.5   Smaller
0.52   Smaller
78.5   Greater
29.8   Smaller
45     Greater
13     Smaller
21.45  Smaller
0.02   Smaller
0.99   Smaller
1.00   Smaller
```

You can feed `bc` multiple expressions, and it will return with one answer per line.

---

If you use another shell (zsh or ksh) you don't need any external tools:

```bash
while IFS= read -r num; do
    printf '%s\t' "$num"
    (( num > 30 )) && print Greater || print Smaller
done < test.txt
```

Comment: As a new programmer, I'm sure this will incomprehensible. But try to break it into individual pieces to see how they fit together: start with `sed "s/\$/ > $cmp/" test.txt` then `sed "s/\$/ > $cmp/" test.txt | bc`; read the `paste` man page to see what it does, and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's always safer to add unary `"+"` in front of variables and fields to ensure the comparison must be done numerically, leaving nothing to chance or implementation peculiarities

*( it's same as `x + 0` with less verbosity; `+ x` is a syntax error due to extra space)* :

> ```
> {m,g}awk '$++NF = +__ < +$_ ? " >" : "<="' OFS='\t' __=30
> ```

```
10.5   <=
0.52   <=
78.5    >
29.8   <=
45      >
13     <=
21.45  <=
0.02   <=
0.99   <=
1.00   <=
```